# implement maven artifact with additional properties in gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my pom file I have one artifact like below:

```
 <artifactItem>
       <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
       <artifactId>xyz.abc</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <classifier>pqr</classifier>
       <type>js</type>
       <overWrite>true</overWrite>
       <outputDirectory>/opt/test</outputDirectory>
       <destFileName>test.js</destFileName>
 </artifactItem>
```

How to implement this in my build.gradle. I am using gradle 2.6.

Sorry, I cannot post original code so put some unrealistic values. Please reply

Answer (score 0):

WIth gradle you can use the maven plugin.
You can find the full doc for the 2.6 [here](https://docs.gradle.org/2.6/userguide/maven_plugin.html).

I don't know if you can set all attributes, but you can use a script like this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.groupId = GROUP
                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                pom.version = VERSION_NAME

                repository(url: "...") {
                    authentication(userName: "user", password: "pass")
                }
                snapshotRepository(url: "...") {
                    authentication(userName: "user", password: "pass")
                }

                pom.project {
                    name POM_NAME
                    packaging POM_PACKAGING
                    description POM_DESCRIPTION
                    url POM_URL

                    scm {
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                        developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                            url POM_LICENCE_URL
                            distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                            name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    signing {
        required { true }
        sign configurations.archives
    }    

    artifacts {
        archives xxxx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i created a gradle task

```
task test <<{
copy {
    from --dir---
    into --dir--
    rename { String fileName -> 
        fileName.replace("xyz.abc-$1.0-pqr","user-prefs")
      }
    }
 }
```

It worked for me.